# NSMutableArray and UITableVIew ( exc_bad_access)

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios5, exc-bad-access

I have object "Consumo"

```
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)consumo{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        fechaLectura = [consumo objectForKey:@"fechaLectura"];
        tarifa = [consumo objectForKey:@"tarifa"];
        consumoBase = [consumo objectForKey:@"consumoBase"];
        consumoHP = [consumo objectForKey:@"consumoHP"];
        reactivoLeido = [consumo objectForKey:@"reactivoLeido"];
        reactivoFacturado = [consumo objectForKey:@"reactivoFacturado"];
        demandaFPLeida = [consumo objectForKey:@"demandaFPLeida"];
        demandaFPFacturada = [consumo objectForKey:@"demandaFPFacturada"];
        demandaHPLeida = [consumo objectForKey:@"demandaHPLeida"];
        demandaHPFacturada = [consumo objectForKey:@"demandaHPFacturada"];
        calificacion = [consumo objectForKey:@"consumo"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

viewController.h

```
   @interface ConsumoViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>  {
    IBOutlet UILabel * sumLabel;
    NSMutableArray * consumos;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tablaConsumo;
    NSMutableArray * titulosConsumo;
    Consumo * cons;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel * sumLabel; 
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray * consumos;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITableView * tablaConsumo;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray * titulosConsumo;
@property (nonatomic,retain) Consumo * cons;
@end
```

viewcontroller.m ( include tableview )

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        consumos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSDictionary * dict;

        for (int i = 0; i < [suministro count]; i++){ /* suministro = array to dictionary */

            dict=[suministro objectAtIndex:i];
            cons = [[Consumo alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
            [consumos insertObject:cons atIndex:i];
        }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

 detFechaLectura = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 20.0, 120.0, 20.0)] autorelease];
        detFechaLectura.tag = LABELSUP1;
[cell.contentView addSubview:detFechaLectura];
}else{
  detFechaLectura = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:LABELSUP1];
}

 detFechaLectura.text = [[consumos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] fechaLectura];

 return cell

}
```

}

Problem:

detFechaLectura.text = [[consumos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] fechaLectura];
  ( Thread 1: Program received signal : "EXC_BAD_ACCESS")

I hope I can help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to do with memory management. You need to `retain` the objects from your dictionary in your `init` method :

```
fechaLectura = [[consumo objectForKey:@"fechaLectura"] retain];
```

---

If your property is set to retain then you must use `self.` to access it like this :

```
self.fechaLectura = [consumo objectForKey:@"fechaLectura"];
```

Comment: great, thanks. I thought about doing this:
        @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString * fechaLectura;
the Retain going to count how many times is initialized.

Comment: See my edit :) If you use `self.fechaLectura` then you are using the property (and therefore the retain). If you just use `fechaLectura` then you must do the retain yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the properties not the instance variables, to properly retain your values.

```
if (self != nil)
{
    self.fechaLectura = [consumo objectForKey:@"fechaLectura"];
    self.tarifa = [consumo objectForKey:@"tarifa"];
    self.consumoBase = [consumo objectForKey:@"consumoBase"];
    self.consumoHP = [consumo objectForKey:@"consumoHP"];
    self.reactivoLeido = [consumo objectForKey:@"reactivoLeido"];
    self.reactivoFacturado = [consumo objectForKey:@"reactivoFacturado"];
    self.demandaFPLeida = [consumo objectForKey:@"demandaFPLeida"];
    self.demandaFPFacturada = [consumo objectForKey:@"demandaFPFacturada"];
    self.demandaHPLeida = [consumo objectForKey:@"demandaHPLeida"];
    self.demandaHPFacturada = [consumo objectForKey:@"demandaHPFacturada"];
    self.calificacion = [consumo objectForKey:@"consumo"];
}
```

And in the dealloc method you need to release each one of those without the `self.`

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [fechaLectura release];
    // ... 
    [calificacion release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: is necessary to eliminate consumo.m? not enough:

[cons release] in ViewController?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by eliminate consumo.m. But whenever you retain an object for a class you need to also release it in the dealloc method.